# How can I count how many char, string, integer, and float or double are in this variable?

Tags: java, types, split, count

```
String str = "I will give you a 20.5 rupees instead of 20";
```

How can I count how many char, string, integer, and float or double are in this variable?

Something like this:

```
char chars = 2; // "I" and "a"
String strings = 6; // "will", "give", "you", "rupees","instead" and "of"
int ints = 1; // 20 
double doubles = 1; // 20.5
```

I want to the output to be something like this :

char 2 string 6 int 1 float 1

I  practice working on it :

```
int s,f,d,c,i;
String [] splited = str.split("\\s+");
for(int i=0;i<splited.length;i++)
{
    String typee=splited[i].getClass.getName();
    if(typee==string){   
        s=s+1;}
    else if(typee=integer){
        i=i+1;
    }
    else if(typee=float){
        f=f+1;
    }
    else if(typee=char){
        c=c+1;
    }
    else if(typee=double){
        d=d+1;
    }
}
System.out.println("String "+s+"\n int "+i+"\n float "+f+"\n char "+c+"\n double "+d);
```

Comment: Split by space then check what each token is, e.g. it is only 1 character long, does it error when you try parse it as an integer etc.

Comment: There are none of those things "in" the string, it's just text.  How you classify them is up to you; for example, the character sequence two, zero could be an integer, a floating point number, just some characters, etc.   It doesn't **become** one of those things until you write and execute code to **convert** it to one of those things.  So, your attempt to get the class name of a section of a string is always going to tell you it is a string.

Comment: yes it is giving me string only so How can i get **appropriate data type** .for that strings

Answer (score 0):

As @dangling else said in the comment you need to convert to respective datatypes and you have to maintain order. Because if you don't maintain the [data type hierarchy](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-data-types) you will always get the wrong output.

Here is my tryout, there can be a better approach than this.

```
String str = "I will give you a 20.5 rupees instead of 20";
String array[] = str.split("\\s+");
int noofChars=0,noofString=0,noofDouble=0,noOfFloat=0,noofInt =0;
for(String arr : array){

    //Parsing to Integer if succesfull then proced to the next one
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(arr);
        noofInt++;
        continue;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
    //Parsing to Float if succesfull then proced to the next one
    try{
        Float.parseFloat(arr);
        noOfFloat++;
        continue;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
    //Parsing to Double if succesfull then proced to the next one
    try{
        Double.parseDouble(arr);
        noofDouble++;
        continue;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
    // If we are here that means its either character or string .
    // easiest way to check  if length == 1 then its a character
    if(arr.length()==1){
        noofChars++;
        continue;                
    }else{
        noofString++;
    }         
    
    
}

System.out.println("String "+noofString+"\n int "+noofInt+"\n char "+noofChars+"\n double "+noofDouble+"\n float "+noOfFloat);
```

Had to use `try-catch` to ensure that if it fails to parse the program should not end abruptly and proceed to check the next datatype.

Comment: Thank you @SayanBhattacharya for this ans it is working fine but when str are having multiple spaces it is counting extra spaces as a string to avoid that we have to **split like this .  String array[] = str.split("\\s+");**

Comment: Yeah, I have considered single space only. Updated ans.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "I will give you a 20.5 rupees instead of 20";
        String[] array = str.split("\\s", -1);
        int chars = 0;
        int strings = 0;
        int ints = 0;
        int doubles = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            if(array[i].matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
                if(array[i].length() == 1){
                    chars = chars + 1;
                }
                else{
                    strings = strings + 1;
                }
            }
            if(array[i].matches("[0-9]+")){
                ints = ints + 1;
            }
            if(array[i].matches("[+-]?\\d+\\.?(\\d+)?")){
                doubles = doubles + 1;
            }
        }
        doubles = doubles - ints;
        
        System.out.println("chars: "+ String.valueOf(chars));
        System.out.println("strings: "+  String.valueOf(strings));
        System.out.println("ints: "+ String.valueOf(ints));
        System.out.println("doubles: "+ String.valueOf(doubles));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @ YasithNirmana  sir for this logic I am also looking for this logic .But sir in this logic  I have **not understand** `if(array[i].matches("[+-]?\\d+\\.?(\\d+)?")){}` this part and also how can we know float value count ?

Comment: The solution will yield wrong results on large numbers like `1234123471092374198237419234719247` which the solution would count as `int` but are out of range.

Comment: Then we have to use a **long data type**  here for large numbers. isn't it sir @ChristianHujer

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputStr = "I will give you a 20.5 rupees instead of 20";
    System.out.println("Decimals:");
    Matcher decimalMatches = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+)").matcher(inputStr);
    while (decimalMatches.find()) {
        System.out.print(Double.parseDouble(decimalMatches.group()) + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Integers:");
    Matcher integerMatches = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)").matcher(inputStr);

    while (integerMatches.find()) {
        System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(integerMatches.group()) + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Characters:");
    Matcher charMatches = Pattern.compile("(^\\w\\s|\\s\\w$|\\s\\w\\s)").matcher(inputStr);
    while (charMatches.find()) { 
        System.out.print(charMatches.group(1) + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Words:");
    Matcher wordMatches = Pattern.compile("(\\w{2,})").matcher(inputStr);

    while (wordMatches.find()) {
        String d = wordMatches.group(1);
        try {
            Integer.valueOf(d);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.print(d + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Decimals:
20.5 
Integers:
20 5 20 
Characters:
I   a  
Words:
will give you rupees instead of
```